# unable to create new native thread in Suse 12 SP2

Tags: multithreading

I am using the Linux 12 SP2 . It always failed to create the thread when the thread is more than 420 .

**Error log**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread (424 threads running, rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 30654, NOFILE 16394, AS infinity, DATA infinity, CPU infinity, FSIZE infinity, MEMLOCK 64k , Memory: 4k page, physical 528062120k(345461208k free), swap 2097148k(2097148k free)  )
```

From the log, you can see the server capacity is good enough for more thread creation. Actually there is quite a few thread is running under OS . Do you have any idea about this issue ?
See below details :

```
ps -aux | wc -l
379
cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
65530
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
32768
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
4125328

ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 2062664
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 8192
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 30654
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Is this 32-bit application ? If yes, then you have run out of address space not memory...

Comment: how to check the application 32-bit ? I just simply use jdk to execute the java class for create many thread to check max thread of this OS . The only thing I can confirm the OS is 64 bit. 
    uname -a
    Linux build8 4.4.21-69-default #1 SMP Tue Oct 25 10:58:20 UTC 2016 (9464f67) x86                                                                                                             _64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You should check the bitness of the JRE/JVM in this case...